# netmiko menu with IP file

Tags: python

I'm having problems with my code - the code itself has user interaction ( menu ) and contains a file with the switch that netmiko will have to ssh and send the commands, my concern is that the file that contains the IP only read 1 IP address although I do have multiple in it.

If I do a `print(devices)` before the `while True`, I can see all the IP listed.

If I do a `print` in the `while True` I can only see the last IP.

here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/1a6kC28b

```
with open('./devices_ip/devices_file') as f:
    devices_list = f.read().splitlines()
    for devices in devices_list:
        ip_address_of_device = devices
        Cisco_device = {
       'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
       'ip': ip_address_of_device,
       'username': username,
       'password': password
     }
        ICX_device = {
        'device_type': 'ruckus_fastiron',
        'ip': ip_address_of_device,
        'username': username,
        'password': password
     }  
        hp_device = {
        'device_type': 'hp_procurve',
        'ip': ip_address_of_device,
        'username': username,
        'password': password
     }

# Loop menu in case incorrect option is selected, and user declines confirming menu option
while True: 
    print "\n"
    print "------------------ Nettools v2 ------------------ \n"
    print "1) SSH Switches & Push commands"
    print "2) Setup VLAN (Work in progress)"
    print "9) Exit menu\n"
    menuChoice = raw_input("Choose a menu option: ")
    elif menuChoice == '1':
    while True: 
        model = raw_input("\nEnter the models type of your switch: " )
        if model != 'HP' and model != 'Cisco' and model != 'ICX':
            print "\nPlease enter HP , Cisco or ICX only. \n"
            continue
        elif model == 'HP':
            r5 = r5_connect()
            output = r5.send_config_set(commands_list_hp)
            r5.disconnect()
            print output
            print "\n Connection has been established and commands has been pushed successfully for your HP Devices...\n"
            break
```

any suggestion on how to fix the issue during the while True:

thanks

Comment: Quentin, your indentation is all wrong, and when you pasted the code something went wrong because you have a hanging `elif` w/o a preceding `if` and this raises a `SyntaxError`!!! — that said I wonder if you want to ask the menu for every device listed in the file, because this is not what your code can do.  Please fix the code as quoted in the question, verifying that what we see is what you have on your machine.

Comment: the script should go through all the device list once all the choice are made without asking the user - I've started to take a look at python 2 days ago, I'll see I'll see about my indentation, hopefully I'll be able to fix it! thanks Franndy